# error when updating my branch by merging from trunk

Tags: svn, branch, merge-conflict-resolution, svn-trunk

I need to get the latest changes from trunk into my branch, so i executed a `svn merge ^/trunk/FW` which until now has worked just fine (with minor conflicts that I've been able to fix manually). But I'm now getting a conflict that I don't know how to fix or even read/understand:

```
Conflict discovered when trying to add 'src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console'.
An object of the same name already exists.
Select: (mf) my version, (tf) their version, (p) postpone,
        (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

What does this mean, why does it pop-up and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**
So I tried to move it to a temporary location with:
`mv src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console ~/tmp/jpax_vip_console` and then I selected `tf (their version)` upon which I'm told: 
`svn: E155027: Tree conflict can only be resolved to 'working' state; '/home/ron/src/NextGen/branches/Ron/src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console' not resolved`. 
Okay, so I go again with `svn merge ^/trunk/FW` and now it tells me: `svn: E195016: Merge tracking not allowed with missing subtrees; try restoring these items first: /home/ron/src/NextGen/branches/Ron/src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console`
So I guess this is not the correct way to do it, but what is then?

**EDIT2**
Okay, so now, after resolving a few other conflicts, I have completed the merge and now on commit I get this:

```
$ svn ci -m " merged changes from trunk"
svn: E155015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155015: Aborting commit: '/home/ron/src/NextGen/branches/Ron/src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console' remains in conflict
```

Why does it say it remains in conflict, svn stat gives me:

```
...
    > moved to src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console.2
...
...
  C src/rtos_core/jpax_bsp_vip/jpax_vip_console
  >   local dir obstruction, incoming dir add upon merge
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original conflict arose because the `jpax_vip_console` file/folder was added in the trunk and your branch independently. When you try to merge trunk now, svn does not know what to do, since both versions of `jpax_vip_console` are unrelated.

The easiest solution would be to rename the problematic entity *using svn commands*, ie something like `svn mv jpax_vip_console jpax_vip_console.2`. Then commit. Afterwards, you should be able to merge trunk without conflict.

If you want to actually merge the two versions of `jpax_vip_console`, you have to do it manually after the trunk merge , as svn does not allow you to content-merge unrelated items. In that case you need to pick one version of the item, for which you would like to keep the commit history, and hand-merge the other version into it.

Comment: Hi,
Please see **EDIT2** above